# How to return a node stream request data in a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have sample code as following.

```
var getPostedData =  function (request) {
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });     
    return qs.parse(body);
};
getPostedData();
```

But the connection request data is coming as stream or multiple data packets. It cannot be returned as like above code in node **v0.12**. The sample code will work with node **v0.10**.

One solution to multiple data packets is to listen `end` event emit on request object.

```
var getPostedData =  function (request) {
        var qs = require('querystring');
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString();
        }).on('end', function() {
            //Here body will have multiple data packets
            //return qs.parse(body);
        });     
        return qs.parse(body);
    };
    getPostedData();
```

But here we can't get return value because of asynchronous nature. 
How to return full multiple data chunks in a function/method?

Comment: @Bergi This is not a duplicate of the question linked. It's related, not exact  duplicate. The scenario that need to be handle have difference in server side javascript and client side javascript.

Comment: Whether it's an ajax `onload` response or an eventemitter `onend` value, both are about "returning" a value from an asynchronous callback. The solutions (callback, promise) are exactly the same.

Comment: @Bergi The post says that sample code works in older version of node, not in newer one. It shows difference. I don't see similar ajax behaviour.

Comment: Uh, I'm pretty sure it didn't work with node v0.10 either (`request` hardly ever was synchronous, like sjax). If you will focus ([edit]) your question on why it worked with 0.10 but no more with 0.12 I can reopen it, but currently it just asks how to make it work which is answered by the dupe

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: [How to ensure asynchronous code is executed after a stream is finished processing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30465092/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a callback function to know when the job done in async.

```
var getPostedData =  function (request, callback) {
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk.toString();
    }).on('end', function() {
        callback(null, qs.parse(body));
    }).on('error' function(err){
        callback(err);
    });
};

router.post("/example", function(req, res, next){
  getPostedData(req, function(err, body){
    if(err) return next(err);
    req.body = body;
    next();
  });
}, function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  // Do you favor
});
```

At there I user your `getPostData` function as a middle-ware on `/example` router.

Comment: Thank you @green. I would like to do this in synchronous style without a callback. Is there any way do so?

Comment: @JustinJohn you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), that is another way of handling callbacks. Then nature of nodejs is already async I/O so you can't do synchronous without callback/promise.

Comment: @JustinJohn or you could use `async` for that (see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729135/how-to-ensure-an-asynchronous-call-is-executed-before-returning-from-a-function/)

Comment: @JustinJohn I not recommend to use `async` at that point (`getPostedData`), because it already in event loop **(promise)**, example `on('data', callback)`.